# Multiple datepart functions as parameters in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes, datepart

I've got a query that works perfectly that I'm trying to turn into a stored procedure that allows a user to input parameters for month and then for two years to show a YOY comparison for that month. The Query that works is below.

```
WITH sales AS (
    SELECT customer_id, customer, [2022] AS [CY sales], [2021] AS [PY sales]
    FROM (
            SELECT customer_id, customer_name AS customer, DATEPART(yyyy, invoice_date) AS [year], SUM(sales_price) AS sales
            FROM sales_history
            WHERE DATEPART(mm, invoice_date) = '8' AND DATEPART(yyyy, invoice_date) IN ('2022', '2021')
            GROUP BY customer_id, customer_name, DATEPART(yyyy, invoice_date)
        ) AS src
    PIVOT (
        SUM(sales) FOR [year] IN ([2022], [2021])
        ) AS salespvt),
profit AS (
    SELECT customer_id, customer, [2022] AS [CY profit], [2021] AS [PY profit]
    FROM (
            SELECT customer_id, customer_name AS customer, DATEPART(yyyy, invoice_date) AS [year], SUM(sales_price-line_other_cost) AS profit
            FROM sales_history
            WHERE DATEPART(mm, invoice_date) = '8' AND DATEPART(yyyy, invoice_date) IN ('2022', '2021')
            GROUP BY customer_id, customer_name, DATEPART(yyyy, invoice_date)
        ) AS src
    PIVOT (
        SUM(profit) FOR [year] IN ([2022], [2021])
        ) AS profitpvt)
SELECT s.customer_id, s.customer, CONCAT(ct.first_name, ' ', ct.last_name) AS [Sales Rep], 
    COALESCE(s.[CY sales], 0) AS [CY Sales], COALESCE(p.[CY profit], 0) AS [CY Profit], COALESCE(p.[CY profit]/NULLIF(s.[CY sales], 0), 0) AS [CY GP],
    COALESCE(s.[PY sales], 0) AS [PY Sales], COALESCE(p.[PY profit], 0) AS [PY Profit], COALESCE(p.[PY profit]/NULLIF(s.[PY sales], 0), 0) AS [PY GP],
    COALESCE(s.[CY sales], 0)-COALESCE(s.[PY sales], 0) AS [Sales Growth], COALESCE((s.[CY sales]-s.[PY sales])/NULLIF(s.[PY sales], 0), 1) AS [Sales Growth %],
    COALESCE(p.[CY profit], 0)-COALESCE(p.[PY profit], 0) AS [Profit Growth], COALESCE((p.[CY profit]-p.[PY profit])/NULLIF(p.[PY profit], 0), 1) AS [Profit Growth %]
FROM sales AS s 
    INNER JOIN profit AS p ON s.customer_id = p.customer_id
    INNER JOIN customer AS c ON s.customer_id = c.customer_id
    INNER JOIN contacts AS ct ON c.salesrep_id = ct.id
ORDER BY [CY Sales] DESC;
```

I'm attempting to make the procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_YOYmonthly_sales_by_customer @month int, @year1 int, @year2 int
AS
WITH sales AS (
    SELECT customer_id, customer, [@year1] AS [CY sales], [@year2] AS [PY sales]
    FROM (
            SELECT customer_id, customer_name AS customer, DATEPART(yyyy, invoice_date) AS [year], SUM(sales_price) AS sales
            FROM sales_history
            WHERE DATEPART(mm, invoice_date) = @month AND DATEPART(yyyy, invoice_date) IN (@year1, @year2)
            GROUP BY customer_id, customer_name, DATEPART(yyyy, invoice_date)
        ) AS src
    PIVOT (
        SUM(sales) FOR [year] IN ([@year1], [@year2])
        ) AS salespvt),
profit AS (
    SELECT customer_id, customer, [@year1] AS [CY profit], [@year2] AS [PY profit]
    FROM (
            SELECT customer_id, customer_name AS customer, DATEPART(yyyy, invoice_date) AS [year], SUM(sales_price-line_other_cost) AS profit
            FROM sales_history
            WHERE DATEPART(mm, invoice_date) = @month AND DATEPART(yyyy, invoice_date) IN (@year1, @year2)
            GROUP BY customer_id, customer_name, DATEPART(yyyy, invoice_date)
        ) AS src
    PIVOT (
        SUM(profit) FOR [year] IN ([@year1], [@year2])
        ) AS profitpvt)
SELECT s.customer_id, s.customer, CONCAT(ct.first_name, ' ', ct.last_name) AS [Sales Rep], 
    COALESCE(s.[CY sales], 0) AS [CY Sales], COALESCE(p.[CY profit], 0) AS [CY Profit], COALESCE(p.[CY profit]/NULLIF(s.[CY sales], 0), 0) AS [CY GP],
    COALESCE(s.[PY sales], 0) AS [PY Sales], COALESCE(p.[PY profit], 0) AS [PY Profit], COALESCE(p.[PY profit]/NULLIF(s.[PY sales], 0), 0) AS [PY GP],
    COALESCE(s.[CY sales], 0)-COALESCE(s.[PY sales], 0) AS [Sales Growth], COALESCE((s.[CY sales]-s.[PY sales])/NULLIF(s.[PY sales], 0), 1) AS [Sales Growth %],
    COALESCE(p.[CY profit], 0)-COALESCE(p.[PY profit], 0) AS [Profit Growth], COALESCE((p.[CY profit]-p.[PY profit])/NULLIF(p.[PY profit], 0), 1) AS [Profit Growth %]
FROM sales AS s 
    INNER JOIN profit AS p ON s.customer_id = p.customer_id
    INNER JOIN customer AS c ON s.customer_id = c.customer_id
    INNER JOIN contacts AS ct ON c.salesrep_id = ct.id
ORDER BY [CY Sales] DESC;
```

But I run into the below errors

> Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
> The incorrect value "@year1" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.

I've attempted declaring the parameters as different datatypes and using CAST to change the datatypes for [year] in the pivot queries but always get the same error.

Comment: You can't pass code, much less functions, as parameters. Parameters can only be used to pass values. In a `PIVOT` clause you're specifying column names, not values

Comment: `[year] IN ([@year1], [@year2])` isn't doing what you *think* it is. It doesn't mean where the value of `year` is in the *values* of the parameters `@year2`, and `@year2` it means where the value of `year` *equals* the **literal (string) value** `'@year1'` or `'@year2'`. As, presumably, the column `Year` is an `int`, then it attempts to convert the value `'@year1'` to an `int`, and obviously that fails.

Comment: I suspect you you *actually* might need is some conditional aggregation, as then you could parametrise it: `SUM(CASE Year WHEN @Year1 THEN profit END) AS Year1`

Comment: What are you trying to do? There probably far easier ways to do it. For example, using a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) makes all date-based reporting a *lot* easier.  Instead of trying to calculate years and quarters, you only need to use the precalculated Year, Quarter, Month fields. Same for year-over-year. You can use eg `LEAD` or `LAG` over the Year column to get the equivalent value of the previous year.

Comment: You could reduce all this code to something like `with totals as (SELECT CustomerId,Year, SUM(Sales_Value) as Total From SalesHistory h inner Join Calendar c on c.Date=h.Date GROUP BY CustomerId,Year) select Year, Total, LAG(Total) OVER (ORDER BY Year FROM totals) As Previous FROM totals;`

Comment: I was able to use a dynamic query to get what I was looking for.